# How to start an instance from another instance in the same project (GCP)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have 2 instances in one project in GCP. One needs to be turned on and off at will from the other one. So inside one instance I try to use `gcloud compute instances start instance1 --zone==us-east1-b` and I get `ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.start) HTTPError 403: Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.`

I've made a custom role with compute.instances.start permission and gave it to every user trying to get it to work but I still get the same error. Can someone point me into the right direction to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to start and stop an instance through other instance in GCP, you need to set the correct access scope to allow the operation that you want to do.

In your case, you need to set the access scope for `Compute Engine` to `read write` in the instance where you are running the commands to start and stop the other instance.
To configure the access scope for an instance you need to stop the instance and then edit the instance, then, on the Access scopes section, you can configure each Access scope as you can see in the documentation [1](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#changeserviceaccountandscopes).

Also, you need to have the correct permissions to be able to run the gcloud command. In your case, to be able to start and stop an instance, at least you need to have the following permissions as you can see in the documentation [2](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stop-start-instance#stopping_an_instance):

- Compute.instances.stop
- compute.instances.start